# Creating multiple rectangles in JAVA

Tags: java

I'm looking to create multiple rectangles using the `Rectangle` object.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    for(int x = 0; x<= cars.size()-1; x++)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        r.setBounds((int) cars.get(x).getX(), (int) cars.get(x).getDistance(), 10, 20);
        g.fillRect(  (int) r.getCenterX(), (int) r.getCenterY(), (int) r.getWidth(), (int) r.getHeight());
    }
}
```

I need the Rectangle object so I can use it to detect collision with another car. The above draws the rectangular "cars". What I need is another smaller rectangle but with a different color. So I'd also like to incorporate color into this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first off, you probably shouldn't be calling `new` in your render code every time you need a rectangle. Keep a `List` of some user defined type at the class level, and maintain separate instances of that.

```
class Foobar {
  private List<Car> cars;
  public Foobar() {
    // create your cars, put them in the list
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (Car car : cars) {
      g2d.setColor(car.color);
      g2d.fill(car.rect);
    }
  }
}

class Car {
  Rectangle rect;
  Color color;
  // constructors etc.
}
```

Comment: I understand. But wouldn't this create multiple rectangles with all having the same color? Reason why is because I wanted to make a smaller rectangle within the one's made with a different color; pretty much to show the center.

Comment: No. That's why you maintatin different instances of the `Car` class -- each one has it's own color associated with it. For your second rectangle, you can just add it as an instance variable to the `Car` class.

Comment: @Dimitri I'd appreciate if you accepted the answer, then :p

Comment: Of course, of course!

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a `Color` attribute to you `Car` class.

You should avoid overriding the `paint` method and instead use `paintComponent`, check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

If you're overriding `paint` of a top level container, you really should, move you painting to something like `JPanel` instead, if for no other reason, it's double buffered.